# Set a Tkinter window as a background for the others

Tags: python, tkinter, syntax, toplevel

I want to make a program with a setup but if the user is clicking in the fullscreen window while the second window is on the screen the second window goes in the back of the fullscreen window and the user needs to restart the program. I would like something oposite from the  win.attributes('-topmost',True) command

I don't know anything to fix even if i've searched on google but I get only the oposite. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is the *second window* created by same program? Or it may be from other programs?

Comment: You can make the other windows *transient* windows of the fullscreen window by calling `win.transient(fullscreen_window)` (`win` is the second window and `fullscreen_window` is the background/fullscreen window).  I would suggest you to create a custom class which inherits from `Toplevel` and call `.transient(...)` inside the class `__init__()`.  Then use this class for all the windows other than the fullscreen window.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want a second smaller window (maybe a popup) to not go behind another fullscreen window. You can use `wm_attributes('-topmost', True)` for this. `wm_attributes('-topmost', True)` forces the window that has the attribute to be on top of other windows. You can apply it to any window using `window_name.wm_attributes('-topmost', True)`. Below is a basic example of something you could do:

```
# Imports
import tkinter as tk

# Create the root window
window = tk.Tk()
window.overrideredirect(True)
window.withdraw()

# Create the fullscreen window
fullscreen_window = tk.Toplevel()
fullscreen_window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

# Create the second window
popup = tk.Toplevel()
popup.geometry('300x200')
popup.wm_attributes('-topmost', True)

# Exit button
exit_button = tk.Button(popup, text="Exit", command=exit)
exit_button.pack()




window.mainloop()
```

Comment: yea but there is not just a second window, there are more windows, and the problem is that I don't want that every other window to be on a "different layer".

Comment: I want just a window to be like a background for the others and the others to not go in the back of the background window

Comment: Oh, nvm I get it

Comment: I had a mistake in my code, sorry!

Comment: @D4R1U5 You can have seperate windows and apply `wm_attributes('-topmost', True)` to them. I'm glad you managed to fix the issue, if my question helped you, can you accept it